# how to use while in the function if result = 1 then exit

Tags: python, function, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have started learning Python. I wrote this code to check if the number is even or odd. If the number is even, then take that number and divide it by 2. If the number is odd then multiply the number by three and add one.

I don't know where to put the while loop.

My code:

```
def collatz(number):

    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number / 2
    else:
        return 3 * number + 1    
print("Enter the number: ")
qassam = int(input())
print(collatz(qassam))
```

I want to exit when the result of any if conditions == 1. How to do that?

Comment: This is invalid Python. Please fix your indentation (it kind of matters in Python).

Comment: sorry i fix it ... wait the solution

Comment: Why do you wish to use while here? There is no looping required as per your requirement that you have stated

Comment: what should i use ? im trying to solve this practice : https://s22.postimg.cc/jn5h9c0z5/Screenshot_2018-06-02_17-20-42.png

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do, can you tell us how you want the program to work with a little more detail?

Comment: @wwii check the link : https://s22.postimg.cc/jn5h9c0z5/Screenshot_2018-06-02_17-20-42.png

Comment: so you need a loop and call `collatz` until it returns `1`.

Comment: @Daniel yes bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep calling your function while your current number is not 1.  So use `while number != 1`.

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2:
        number = (3 * number) + 1
    else:
        number =  number//2
    print(number)
    return number

number = int(input("Number: "))
while(number != 1):
    number = collatz(number)
```

Comment: thank u for replay but im trying to this : https://s22.postimg.cc/jn5h9c0z5/Screenshot_2018-06-02_17-20-42.png , i dont want to use list's yet

Comment: no not tha't what i want ... When I write the number 10 it is divided into two so it's equal = 5 and the same for 8 when divided for 2 it should equal = 8 ... and for odd if i input 5 it should be 3*5+1 = 16 ..... what im asking for in i input number 2 / 2 = 1 here i need the program to end the loop and exit ... i hope u will get it

Comment: @QassamMahmoud You need to re-read your requirement.  Notice that the program described receives user input only once, then continuously calls `collatz` to change that value until it becomes `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def collatz(number):
    If number%2==0:
        return number //2
    else:
        return 3*number+1
userInput = int(input())
while userInput != 1:
    userInput = collatz(userInput)
    print(userInput)
```

I hope this helps.. 
As per the info in the link you provided every number eventually becomes 1 when you do num//2(floor division as you need only integers not float) for even and 3*num+1 for odds repeatedly on the results

Comment: no not tha't what i want ... When I write the number 10 it is divided into two so it's equal = 5 and the same for 8 when divided for 2 it should equal = 8 ... and for odd if i input 5 it should be 3*5+1 = 16 ..... what im asking for in i input number 2 / 2 = 1 here i need the program to end the loop and exit ... i hope u will get it

Comment: No...read the first line on paragraph 2 on the link for the problem statement..it should keep repeating the process on the same number.. (and not multiple inputs)